# pydantic `json_encoders` for builtin types (float, int, etc)

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I'm having some unexpected behavior with json encoding of fields like `float`, `int`, etc. using pydantic.  Here is the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) for json encoding, for reference.

As an example, this model seems to encode `complex` just fine, but ignores my `float` field.

```py
import pydantic as pd

class Model(pd.BaseModel):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True
        json_encoders = {
            float: lambda x: 'test',
            complex: lambda x: 'test'
        }
    d1:float
    d2:complex

m = Model(d1=1.0, d2=1j)
m.json()
# '{"d1": 1.0, "d2": "test"}'
```

Can anyone shine light on this behavior and point me in the right direction?

My use case is a custom encoder to detect when a `float` is `numpy.inf` and then write it to `"Infinity"` in json rather than the illegal default value of `Infinity` as encoded by the `json` package.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind why your custom json_encoder not working for `float` type is [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) uses `json.dumps()` for serialization.
If any type is serializable with `json.dumps()` it will not use cutom json_encoder for those types.

And come to the `complex` type it's not serializable by `json.dumps()` that's why it's using the custom json_encoder you have provided.

If you still want to use custom json_encoder you can use [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/1.3.0/) as suggested by pydantic.

[Custom JSON (de)serialisation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation)

**Sample Code:**

```
def orjson_dumps(v, *, default):
    for key, value in v.items():
        if isinstance(value, float):
            v[key] = 'test'
        elif isinstance(value, complex):
            v[key] = 'test'
    # orjson.dumps returns bytes, to match standard json.dumps we need to decode
    return orjson.dumps(v, default=default).decode()
    

class Model(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True
        json_dumps = orjson_dumps
        json_loads = orjson.loads
    d1:float
    d2:complex

m = Model(d1=1.0, d2=1j)
m.json() # {"d1":"test","d2":"test"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I assumed that declaring a custom `json_encoder` would override the behavior in `json.dumps`.  I must have missed that part in the documentation.  Appreciate your response